# Printing Map of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, dictionary

What I'm trying to do is log a complex `HashMap<String, Object>` with several kinds of objects and I don't know the structure beforehand. Only problem with the `Map's own`toString`method is that when it runs in to arrays and their own`toString` method the output is less than informative:

```
{array=[Ljava.lang.Object;@6c22c95b}
```

What's the best way I can implement a way to log the `Map`?

Example code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    final Object[] array = new Object[] {"hep", 1, true};
    map.put("array", array);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

output:

```
{array=[Ljava.lang.Object;@6c22c95b}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 possibilities.

First change your map to contain collections instead of arrays. `toString()` method of `AbstractCollection` creates nice view of the collection elements using the `toString` of elements themselves, so if `toString` of your elements is good enough the total view will be readable too.

Other possibility is to iterate over map entries and use `Arrays.toString(arr)` to create string representation of your array. Usually loggers are flexible enough to make it easy to do this out of the box, for example using formatter of log4j.

Comment: The problem with your first suggestion is that I can't change the object, it is as it is. I need to log it and pass it forward.

Comment: I'm using slf4j. Could you be a bit more specific on using the logging formatter?

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate and print the contents of the array like

```
 java.util.Arrays.toString(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really one of the darker corners of Java.

You could use an external library [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/lang/) like which provides [`ReflectionToStringBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html).

Comment: hmm, how does that really work. Just by printing ReflectionToSTringBuilder.toString(map) resulted in java.util.HashMap@68ab95e6[threshold=12,loadFactor=0.75]

Answer (score 0):

Well you could define your own map extending the normal map and overshadowing .toString()
Then in turn checks if objects are instanceof array and handles print differently.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the value Object properly overrides it's `toString` method, you can not print meaningful logs just by printing the Object. But there is a possibility using Java reflection. Using `java.lang.reflect` you have to get the fields (only for public fields) and their values. If the object mentioned by field is not overriding `toString` method, you need to use reflection again.

```
Object object = map.get(key);
Class<?> klass = object.getClass(); // but it supports only public fields
Fields[] fields = klaa.getFields();

for (Field field: fields) {
 // get the values from the field . Check with the API
}
```

In case the fields are private fields and if you are sure that getter methods available for those, then you can call those using reflection and print them.

Answer (score 0):

You're solving the wrong problem. Use a [Guava `Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) instead of a Map of Arrays and everything will work better, including string representation. If you don't want to use an external Library, use a `Map<String, List<Object>>`. All standard List implementations provide proper `toString()` methods.

BTW, a mixed array is usually a code smell. You should try to create an Object representation of your array's contents.

Answer (score 0):

here are a couple of simple utility method that might work.

```
public static String toString(Object[] array) {
    if (array == null) return "null";
    final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("[");
    for (Object o : array) {
        if (b.length() > 0) b.append(", ");
        if (o == null) {
            b.append("null");
        } else if (o instanceof Map) {
            b.append(toString((Map) o));
        } else if (o.getClass().isArray()) {
            b.append(toString((Object[]) o));
        } else {
            b.append(o.toString());
        }
    }
    return b.append("]").toString();
}

public static String toString(Map map) {
    if (map == null) return "null";
    final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("{");
    for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
        final Object value = map.get(key);
        b.append(key).append("=");
        if (value == null) {
            b.append("null");
        } else {
            if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
                b.append(toString((Object[]) value, ", "));
            } else if (value instanceof Map) {
                b.append(toString((Map) value));
            } else {
                b.append(value);
            }
        }
    }
    return b.append("}").toString();
}
```

these are adapted from [cobbzilla-utils](https://github.com/cobbzilla/cobbzilla-utils), my personal handy utility library:

- https://github.com/cobbzilla/cobbzilla-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/org/cobbzilla/util/string/StringUtil.java#L227
- https://github.com/cobbzilla/cobbzilla-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/org/cobbzilla/util/collection/ArrayUtil.java#L98